# Find a tag with a specific suffix using preg_match

Tags: regex, preg-match-all, greedy

I'm looking for tags that end in a specific way using regular expressions in PHP. However all my attempts either result in too much or too little.

For example, in the following string I'd like to match 'bar' because it is in a tag that ends with 'suffix'.

```
preg_match_all("/<(.*?)suffix>/", "<foo> <barsuffix> <baz>"
```

However the above line results in 'foo>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex instead: `/<([^>]*)suffix>/`.

It will not allow things like `foo> <bar`, because `[^>]` ensures that the match souldn't containt `>`.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting some lookbehind stuff but this is even better!